# Index to speed up query

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization

I have this SQL query that I have to speed up:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.attribute1, A.attribute2
FROM table1 A, table2 B
WHERE A.attribute1 = B.attribute3
AND B.attribute4 = 'String';
```

What I am currently doing is creating a hash index on B.attribute3 to speed up the JOIN and creating another hash index on B.attribute4 to speed up the equality with 'String'.

```
CREATE INDEX atr3_idx ON table2 USING HASH (attribute3);
CREATE INDEX atr4_idx ON table2 USING HASH (attribute4);
```

Is there a better way to optimise this query?

Comment: You should also thunk about doing an index on attribute1. But then it all depends on what kind of values you have, the volume, etc... did you already try `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the version of Postgres, the output of `\d` for both tables and the output of `explain  (analyze, buffers) SELECT ..;` ?

Comment: Plus basic information in data distribution in relevant columns and read / write load.

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt would be to add `btree` indexes, not hash ones.

- an index on `B (attribute4, attribute3)` and
- an index on `A (attribute1, attribute2)`

The reasoning behind the suggestion is that the only a small part of the first index on `B` needs to be read, only the part that has `attribute4 = 'String4'` and then the values of `attribute3` will be used for the join, against the other index on `A`.

Comment: I was under the impression that hash indexes were the best for equalities, since I have two equalities I thought they would be the best choice

Comment: @JoaquimVerdasca hash indexes are bad for inequalities / range queries. For equality, while they may be better than normal b-tree indexes, I don't think there is much difference. And when composite indexes are needed, I don't know. To be honest, I've never used hash indexes in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the index in the below manner.

This query should check this first. 
`A.attribute1 = B.attribute3` This covers the `DISTINCT A.attribute1`

```
create index attribute1_idx on table1 USING HASH (attribute1);
create index attribute3_idx on table2 USING HASH (attribute3);
```

Then Index for `B.attribute4 = 'String'`

```
create index attribute4_idx on table2 USING HASH (attribute4);
```

Comment: Does the extra index on attribute1 also speed up the JOIN? Or just the DISTINCT part?